# Enable a stack-based editor tab switch in a Jetbrains IDE, using the KeyMap setting

Tags: webstorm, key-bindings, jetbrains-ide

How can I enable a stack-based tab switch in a JetBrains IDE? I'm looking for something similar to what Eclipse uses as its default tab switcher where each tab that is accessed is placed on a stack, and we can cycle through the stack using a keybinding like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. For example, if I am in `foo.txt` and I switch to `bar.txt`, I want the next tab cycle to be `foo.txt`, regardless of how many tabs I have open. Is this possible?

I have explored the settings under `Editor Tabs` and `Keymap`, but I have not found any relevant settings.

I am open to general suggestions as well, as I'm a bit new to the JetBrains IDE's.

Also, I am trying this on WebStorm and PyCharm with an IDEAVim plug-in, and a customized keymap, running Ubuntu 14.04, if that matters.

Comment: Strange: single quick `Ctrl+Tab` switches between two recent tabs for me (just like `Alt+Tab` does in Windows).

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, I am looking for the functionality like `Alt+Tab`. `Ctrl+Tab` and `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` move to the right and left tabs respectively, and I have tested this on PyCharm and WebStorm. What's your OS? I wonder if this is Ubuntu/Linux specific.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 x64 using PhpStorm v8. Lets try this: press and hold `Ctrl`. Now press (and release) `Tab` once (while still having `Ctrl` pressed). You should see **Switcher** popup window displayed. What tab is preselected for you? Is this the last one used (before current) .. or just next one (on the right). I've checked all my settings and plugins .. and do not see anything that would make it so special to behave like that (running this config since 0.x version)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! The keymap assigns keybindings to `switcher` to control this behavior, which was broken when I imported my own keybindings (answer below). I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! This problem stemmed from an imported keymap that I was using. The imported keymap broke the default stack-based tab switcher, as described in the comments above.

To re-enable the stack-based tab switcher, there is a setting called `switcher` under `Keymaps`. I bound it to `Ctrl`+`Tab` and `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Tab`, and everything works as expected. I had imported my emacs-based key-bindings, which bound `switcher` to `Ctrl`+`x`+`b` by default.

Comment: Wow thanks, so glad you answered this as I was in the same boat.  It's not exactly like stack-based switching in Windows or Visual Studio or Qt Creator or a browser or anything else, as the Shift- version takes you back into Switcher's "other" panes, but it's close.